# Python :Nested for loops fail on the second loop

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

I am trying to divide a large data set into smaller parts for an analysis. I been using a for-loop to divide the data set before implementing the decision trees. Please see a small version of the data set below:

```
ANZSCO4_CODE          Skill_name              Cluster         date
  1110                  computer                 S              1
  1110                  communication            C              1
  1110                  SAS                      S              2
  1312                  IT support               S              1
  1312                  SAS                      C              2
  1312                  IT support               S              1
  1312                  SAS                      C              1
```

First step I create an empty dictionary:

```
d = {}
```

and the lists:

```
 list = [1110, 1322, 2111]
 s_type = ['S','C']
```

Then run the following loop:

```
for i in list:
    d[i]=pd.DataFrame(df1[df1['ANZSCO4_CODE'].isin([i])] )
```

The result is a dictionary with 2 data sets inside.

As a next step I would like to subdivide the data sets into S and C. I run the following code:

```
for i in list:
    d[i]=pd.DataFrame(df1[df1['ANZSCO4_CODE'].isin([i])] )

    for b in s_type:
         d[i]=  d[i][d[i]['SKILL_CLUSTER_TYPE']==b]
```

As a final result I would expect to have 4 separate data sets, being: `1110 x S`, `1110 x C` , `1312 x S` and `1312 and C`.

However when I implement the second code I get only 2 data sets inside the dictionary and they are empty.

Comment: can you please show me, what is in the list variable?

Comment: @user2906838 , sorry I missed that. It is edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there was empty DataFrames, because in data was not values from `list` called `L` (Dont use variable name list, because python reserved word).

```
from  itertools import product

L = [1110, 1312, 2111]
s_type = ['S','C']
```

Then create all combinations all lists:

```
comb = list(product(L, s_type))
print (comb)
[(1110, 'S'), (1110, 'C'), (1312, 'S'), (1312, 'C'), (2111, 'S'), (2111, 'C')]
```

And last create dictionary of `DataFrame`s:

```
d = {}
for i, j in comb:
    d['{}x{}'.format(i, j)] = df1[(df1['ANZSCO4_CODE'] == i) & (df1['Cluster'] == j)]
```

Or use dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'{}x{}'.format(i, j): df1[(df1['ANZSCO4_CODE'] == i) & (df1['Cluster'] == j)] 
      for i, j in comb}
```

---

```
print (d['1110xS'])
   ANZSCO4_CODE Skill_name Cluster
0          1110   computer       S
2          1110        SAS       S
```

EDIT:

If need all combinations of possible data by columns use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
d = {'{}x{}x{}'.format(i,j,k): df2 
      for (i,j, k), df2 in df1.groupby(['ANZSCO4_CODE','Cluster','date'])}
print (d)
{'1110xCx1':    ANZSCO4_CODE     Skill_name Cluster  date
1          1110  communication       C     1, '1110xSx1':    ANZSCO4_CODE Skill_name Cluster  date
0          1110   computer       S     1, '1110xSx2':    ANZSCO4_CODE Skill_name Cluster  date
2          1110        SAS       S     2, '1312xCx1':    ANZSCO4_CODE Skill_name Cluster  date
6          1312        SAS       C     1, '1312xCx2':    ANZSCO4_CODE Skill_name Cluster  date
4          1312        SAS       C     2, '1312xSx1':    ANZSCO4_CODE  Skill_name Cluster  date
3          1312  IT support       S     1
5          1312  IT support       S     1}

print (d.keys())
dict_keys(['1110xCx1', '1110xSx1', '1110xSx2', '1312xCx1', '1312xCx2', '1312xSx1'])
```

Another different approach is if need processes each group is use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def func(x):
    print (x)
    #some code for process each group
    return x

   ANZSCO4_CODE     Skill_name Cluster  date
1          1110  communication       C     1
   ANZSCO4_CODE     Skill_name Cluster  date
1          1110  communication       C     1
   ANZSCO4_CODE Skill_name Cluster  date
0          1110   computer       S     1
   ANZSCO4_CODE Skill_name Cluster  date
2          1110        SAS       S     2
   ANZSCO4_CODE Skill_name Cluster  date
6          1312        SAS       C     1
   ANZSCO4_CODE Skill_name Cluster  date
4          1312        SAS       C     2
   ANZSCO4_CODE  Skill_name Cluster  date
3          1312  IT support       S     1
5          1312  IT support       S     1

df2 = df1.groupby(['ANZSCO4_CODE','Cluster','date']).apply(func)
print (df2)
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the following error : TypeError: 'list' object is not callable when calling comb = list(product(L, s_type))

Comment: Trying naming your list something other than `list`.

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira - Problem is before is used variable `list`, solution is restart your IDE or use `list = builtins.list`

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira - And exactly this is reason why is necessary dont use variable `list` ;)

Comment: @jezrael and @ Ashish Acharya , thanks for both responses, also thanks for advising me to do not use list..@jezrael in a hypothetical scenario if I add a date variable would I be able to do combinations with 3 constraints?

Comment: @Ian_De_Oliveira - One thing, do you want create dictioanry of all possible combinations from DataFrames? Or your `L` and `s_type` and `d_type` contains only some values ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this works:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(pd.DataFrame)

# don't name your list "list"
anzco_list = [1110, 1312]
s_type = ['S','C']

for i in anzco_list:
    for b in s_type:
        d[i][b] = df1[(df1['ANZSCO4_CODE'] == i) & (df1['SKILL_CLUSTER_TYPE'] == b)]
```

Then you can access your DataFrames like this:

```
d[1112]['S']
```

Comment: thanks for your support. I'm getting the following error :ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series

Comment: You can use jezrael's answer below. That seems like a better way to do it.